# Node.JS fs.WriteFile path as a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I am trying to save a simple file to a directory other then my root directory, but it seems to error out when using a variable instead of a direct string.Has anyone tried using a variable or see if i am missing something.
Thanks

```
var procedures = "SomeString";
var moveTo = "C:/SavedFiles";
//////////////////
fs.writeFile(moveTo ,procedures, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        });`
```

Comment: Did you try using backslashes instead (e.g. `var moveTo = 'C:\\SavedFiles';`)?

Comment: not yet but thanks will try that out

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct that "C:/SavedFiles" is a directory? Is so, then specify a file to write to like:

```
var moveTo = "C:/SavedFiles/myfile.txt";
// keep the rest the same
```

Not sure about the slashes though, not running Windows ATM.

Comment: yea i think its somthing else in my code not posted . I will try to update the code , thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like my error was due to a rouge loop above my code not posted. Sorry i didn't post the rest of the code